# Can anyone see a syntax error in this?

Tags: plugins, php, git

My hosting at wp-engine wont allow me to upload this file by git because of a syntax error.
Can anybody see what the error is?

```
<?php
$aryWPMUConfig = get_site_option('wpmu-piwik_global-settings',false);
if (is_plugin_active_for_network('wp-piwik/wp-piwik.php') && $aryWPMUConfig) {
foreach ($aryWPMUConfig as $key => $value) {
    self::$settings->setGlobalOption($key, $value);
}
delete_site_option('wpmu-piwik_global-settings');
self::$settings->setGlobalOption('auto_site_config', true);
} else {
self::$settings->setGlobalOption('auto_site_config', false);
}
self::$settings->setGlobalOption('dashboard_seo' = false);
self::$settings->setGlobalOption('stats_seo', false);
self::$settings->setGlobalOption('track_404', self::$settings->getOption('track_404'));
self::$settings->setGlobalOption('track_compress', false);
self::$settings->setGlobalOption('track_post', false);
```

This is update/90001.php from wp-piwik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setGlobalOption()` call here is different from the rest:

```
self::$settings->setGlobalOption('dashboard_seo' = false);
self::$settings->setGlobalOption('stats_seo', false);
```

I think your `=` should be `,` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. ive been puzzling over this for about 3 hours.

Comment: `WP_DEBUG` is your best friend, sometimes.  Even if you can set yourself up a WordPress installation on `localhost`, and test things before you push them to wpengine.

Comment: I tried that but the plugin installed and ran with no comment even though it contained that error.